# How to check if one whole string is present in part of another string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm using PHP for a school project and I'm trying to run an SQL query that will return a list of entries in a table where they all contain 8 digits of a 12 digit ID. E.g. I have a string containing "0221122017" and I want to query this to return a list of values that resemble "0221122017XXXX". Is there an easy way to do this? I have not been able to find that carries out this sort of function for an SQL Query. I have no problem with the PHP side and running a query etc. I am really just racking my brains as to how this would be done. I hope I have explained my problem well

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? If this is a school project you've surely been given a lecture or reading material on how a `like` statement works... Have you tried consulting those?

Comment: Please read https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: We aren't given reading material on how to do absolutely everything. I feel like I've been searching in all the wrong places because it looks like that like statement is exactly what I need. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE id LIKE '%0221122017%'
```

`LIKE` is followed by a pattern string, and `%` is a wildcard that matches anything.